# Doctrine2 - (how to) fetch associated objects with main

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Assume that i have an association mapping in Doctrine2.

How to define that i need to **fetch all associated objects** while querying the main one?

Practically, if i define (Main 1-* Sub) and then access all items in Sub collection, Doctine will execute a single DB request to get every one Sub object. I need to Sub objects be retrieved in a main query (JOIN).

Comments or (preferably) Doctrine RTMs welcome )

Answer (score 3):

If you need that on constant basis (i.e. always fetch all association), declare your associations [eager](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading). Consult with [Doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/index.html) chapters 17-19 for details.

If you need it in just several pieces of code - use `DQL` for quering them ([manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)). This way you'll have to specify all your associations.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u, a FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

If you are going to use that query often, it isa good idea to encapsulate it in the Entity class (simple, but not best solution), or create a [`Repository`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) for an entity (a bit more involved, but it's "the right way").

Answer (score 0):

UserRepository

```
public function getUsersFromCity($city): Collection
{
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.address', 'a')
    ->addSelect('a')
    ->andWhere('a.city = :city')
    ->setParameter('city', $city)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;

}
```